# Chart-Donut label position

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Would it be possible to put a label inside the hole of the Donut, if so please assist by providing some examples. Thanks in advance.

For example ,see this sample

[image: See this sample]

Comment: If you change the position to `insideEnd` and play about with distance and margins, you should be able to

Answer (score 0):

Make new componetnt with donut chart put a div tag with position:absolute . I've made such a component it works like charm:)